# How to immediately chunk or partition large data that would normally be read by sql into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, large-data

**High level idea:**

I need to iterate over and perform fairly complex operations on a large dataset (240 million rows) that I have chunked into SQL calls that return ~20 million records each. I can successfully pull each chunk into pandas, but those dataframes are unwieldy and really need further chunking or partitioning further before I can operate on them. I unfortunately can not divide the ingestion calls any smaller (the SQL calls are against AWS S3 via Spectrum and would require many costly scans against a nonpartitioned column if so).

Using Python, how can I efficiently further chunk out these large datasets upon ingestion?

**Specific details:**

I have two primary columns to consider `ID` and `Date`. The already established chunks (of 20 million each) are for months in the `Date` column. Within each ingested chunk, the operations I need to perform look like:

- Sort the data by `Date`
- Iterate through each `ID`, get a new dataset filtered to that `ID`
- For each row in each ID's dataset, do some stuff
- Said stuff will allow me to create a new dataset with one row per ID

...then eventually concatenate the result of all of the months. To me, the inference then is that if I can immediately partition each ingested 20 million records by `ID` or sets of such, I'm golden, but I don't know how to reach that.

I could save each `ID` set as a separate csv, but then I'd need to iterate over the pandas dataframe (filtering and then saving), which isn't tenable. I've read about alternatives to scale out of pandas like dask, but it ?seems? like that doesn't really handle ingestion or setting up a big for loop as I need, but rather typical pandas-like data transformations. Having not worked with data such large sizes, I'm not sure what tools are available to approach a problem like this within a Python environment.

Comment: Stepping back, do you really need pandas for this?  Sure, it's convenient to make a single call to read an SQL query into a dataframe, but pandas is big and heavy, and has to read the whole query in.  If you do your processing by hand, you can use a cursor that only pulls over a record at a time.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm definitely not married to pandas - what else I can use is indeed the question! I'd like to stick with Python just because my resources for learning external tools is limited at the moment, but otherwise dandy. Cursors might make sense, I just don't know how to apply to this problem.

Comment: Well, you can ask SQL to sort the rows by `ID` and `Date` , right?  You don't need to duplicate that.  I don't know what processing you need to do on the ID data.  If you do a `for row in cursor.fetch_one():` kind of loop, you can collect rows until the ID changes, and then do whatever computation you need with the ID block you just finished.  That's sketchy, but without having you write out a complete project specification, that's about the best I can do.

Comment: @TimRoberts AWS Spectrum actually doesn't allow `ORDER BY` in that layer (if you use it, it pushes it to the RedShift layer in my understanding, which in my case creates some problems). There are multiple rows per `ID` within a `Date` chunk and I'm essentially concating strings found in each into a running list based on some logic. Is the idea with the cursor to write to a csv/text line-by-line? And if so, does that mean the server is just holding the results set in memory in the meanwhile?

Comment: @TimRoberts after a little more reading, cursors is indeed what I needed. if write it as an answer I'll accept. I was just utterly naive to their existence sadly!

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a minimal reproducible example so I can't work with your specific data.
You can use generators, but chunks are easier and faster to implement so you are on the right track.

I usually chunk huge datasets like that:

```py
    chunk_size = 10000
    for i in range(0, len(column), chunk_size):
        data_chunked = [j for j in column[i:i+chunk_size]] # or any other data manipulation
        entries_to_sql = [data_chunked, *other_entries] # if others are not chunked: other_entry[i:i+chunk_size]
        insert_many_entries_to_sql(entries_to_sql)
```

Comment: I don't think this would work in this case. I noted that I can't chunk the SQL any smaller, so I'm forced to receive ~20million a chunk at a time if I make a standard SQL call like `pd.read_sql()`. Chunking the received 20million would of course make sense, but I noted the specific difficulties on that above.